# Bash script to loop over all sub-directories, check existence of a script directory, and run a script there

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm trying to make a script which uses a `for` loop to find all the folders in the directory where it is started, and then use an `if` statement to find another folder within them which has a name `templates`, in which I then want to run a python command to execute python scripts stored in that folder.

- My directory structure looks like this:

  ```
  all/
      this_script.sh
      one/
          templates/
                    render_j2.py
      two/
          templates/
                    render_j2.py
  ```
- What I've tried for `this_script-sh` is

  ```bash
  for file in *; do
    if [[ "$file"==*"templates"* ]];
    then
      cd $file
    fi
  done
  ```

  and also tried this:

  ```bash
  for file in *; do
  find . templates
  python render_j2.py; 
  done
  ```

My main issue is that I can't enter the `templates` folder, and even when I can, the python command cant find the python files to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using find, why not offload the entire task to it? You could try the following:

```
find . -type f -path "*/templates/render_j2.py" -execdir python render_j2.py \;
```

This will search for all files `render_j2.py` in a directory `templates` below your starting point, and in the directory where the file was found, execute your python command.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of things wrong with this:

- Neither version is testing if `$file` is a directory
- When the first version uses `cd $file` then $file will not be a valid path in the next iteration of the loop, because you changed directories;  putting `cd` in a subshell (using parentheses) along with things you want to do in that directory would fix this.
- In the second version, the find syntax is wrong to do what you want
- it doesn't make sense to run find in a loop like this, find does its own loop internally

Something like this might work:

```
find . -name templates -type d -execdir python {}/render_j2.py \;
```

This would be equivalent to

```
(cd all/one && python ./templates/render_j2.py )
(cd all/two && python ./templates/render_j2.py )
...
```

which still might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of a non-answer but this seems like an over complicated setup. If you have an unstated reason you must or just want (to learn perhaps) the loop then this isn't going to be your answer but...You can do this sans loop with the find command.

Something like

```
find $HOME/my/folders -type d -name templates -exec my.py {} \;
```

Comment: Almost! It looks like the python script needs to be run from within the directory where the `render_j2.py` is located, that's whythe other answers used `-execdir`.

Comment: These three answers were typed pretty much simultaneously.  I almost included --exec instead of -execdir